# How can i print the result in a file after for loop

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

```
for line in sourcefile.splitlines():
   for l in targetfile.splitlines():
      if line in targetfile:
        sourcefile.replace(line, l)

print sourcefile
```

When I run the code, I get the sourcefile without changes. It prints the file in the state before the for looo. How can I get in the sourcefile the result of replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) doesn't modify the string in place, it returns a new string:

> `string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])`
>
> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old
>   replaced by new.

Use:

```
sourcefile = sourcefile.replace(line, l)
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = 'test1'
>>> s.replace('1', '2')
'test2'
>>> s
'test1'
>>> s = s.replace('1', '2')
>>> s
'test2'
```